# Selenium (Python), How do I get the file path after the download completes of each download process using Pool?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I looked at other topics on almost the same issue, but basically the function is implemented for downloading and waiting for one file, getting one path. That's all right.
But what to do when the files are downloaded almost simultaneously, but through the Pool, and the response returns the same file in the directory?

Important: Chromium works in headless mode.

Now I have the following functions working together

```
def download_wait(path_to_downloads):
    seconds = 0
    download_waiting = True
    while download_waiting and seconds < 300:
        time.sleep(1)
        download_waiting = False
        for filename in os.listdir(path_to_downloads):
            if filename.endswith('.crdownload'):
                download_waiting = True
        seconds += 1
    print(f'File downloaded in {seconds} seconds') 

   def last_downloaded_file(download_dir):
    filename = max([f for f in os.listdir(download_dir)], key=lambda xa: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(download_dir, xa)))
    return filename
```

Any ideas for upgrading these features? It is necessary for each Pool to receive its own file.

Comment: One solution will be to make the download by grabbing the link and using the `request` module without going through the browser's download process. This should help getting the file link since, the program needs to define the same to save the file

Comment: Unfortunately, the href is not always available, and the link can be created after a certain time, when you go to the download page, by waiting for the server to serve the file.

But perhaps, if it is possible to intercept the download link from the selenium to the request, I would get the name of the file, and just look for this file with a unique name in the download folder.